# I want to retrieve rows using ref cursor. But getting the below error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

**PLS-00382:expression is of wrong type**

I understand there is something related to for loop but i am not able to mark it.

Below is my query:

```
set serveroutput on;
cl scr();

DECLARE
    type type_cursor_emp is 
      ref cursor return emp%ROWTYPE;
    v_emp_cur1 type_cursor_emp;
    v_emp emp%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN
    open v_emp_cur1 for 
    select emp_id,emp_name from emp;

    Loop
        fetch v_emp_cur1 into v_emp;
        exit when v_emp_cur1%notfound;
        dbms_output.put_line('Emp_id = '||v_emp.emp_id ||',emp_name = '||v_emp.emp_name);

    end loop;

    close v_emp_cur1;
end;

/
```

Comment: I think you want to use `select * from emp`, though you have used `ROWTYPE`

Comment: Hey David i tried using Select *  from emp and its worked. But can not able to see the result even if i write dbms_output.put_line inside the loop. The output only came like anonymous block completed .

Comment: I wanted to understand why its not taking column name like emp_id, emp_name and only took select * from emp .Please help me to understand

Answer (score 1):

OPEN cursor FOR requires a string, and your ref cursor is strongly typed so you must return a full `emp` record, e.g.:

```
open v_emp_cur1 for
'select * from emp';
```

http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/dynamic.htm#LNPLS629

However, in your case it is unclear why you need to use dynamic SQL. You could do it much more simply with a static query, removing the need for a ref cursor:

```
BEGIN
  FOR v_emp IN (
    select emp_id,emp_name from emp
    ) LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Emp_id = '||v_emp.emp_id ||',emp_name = '||v_emp.emp_name);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Jeffrey Kemp. Actually i m trying to write code using OPEN FOR statement with using ref cursor

Comment: Because i leaning coding now. So just wanted to know how to use ref cursor

Comment: If you're just learning to code, I would not start with dynamic SQL. Master the simpler tasks first, then you'll have the background you need to tackle more complex problems.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. Sure i will do .

Answer (score 0):

The way you are doing it, it could be simplified to a simple **cursor for loop**.

```
SQL> BEGIN
  2    FOR i IN
  3    ( SELECT empno,ename FROM emp
  4    )
  5    LOOP
  6      dbms_output.put_line('Emp_id = '||i.empno ||',emp_name = '||i.ename);
  7    END LOOP;
  8  END;
  9  /
Emp_id = 7369,emp_name = SMITH
Emp_id = 7499,emp_name = ALLEN
Emp_id = 7521,emp_name = WARD
Emp_id = 7566,emp_name = JONES
Emp_id = 7654,emp_name = MARTIN
Emp_id = 7698,emp_name = BLAKE
Emp_id = 7782,emp_name = CLARK
Emp_id = 7788,emp_name = SCOTT
Emp_id = 7839,emp_name = KING
Emp_id = 7844,emp_name = TURNER
Emp_id = 7876,emp_name = ADAMS
Emp_id = 7900,emp_name = JAMES
Emp_id = 7902,emp_name = FORD
Emp_id = 7934,emp_name = MILLER

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

In `SQL*Plus` you could easily do it using a **refcursor** variable.

```
SQL> var r refcursor
SQL>
SQL> BEGIN
  2    OPEN :r FOR SELECT empno,ename FROM emp;
  3  END;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print r

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7369 SMITH
      7499 ALLEN
      7521 WARD
      7566 JONES
      7654 MARTIN
      7698 BLAKE
      7782 CLARK
      7788 SCOTT
      7839 KING
      7844 TURNER
      7876 ADAMS

     EMPNO ENAME
---------- ----------
      7900 JAMES
      7902 FORD
      7934 MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Jeffrey Lalit. Actually i m trying to write code using OPEN FOR statement with using ref cursor

Comment: Second solution uses OPEN FOR statement using ref cursor variable.

Comment: Yes .That i have done .its resolved now according to the below query.

Comment: set serveroutput on;
cl scr();
DECLARE
type t_emp_cursor is 
ref cursor return emp%ROWTYPE;
v_emp_cur t_emp_cursor;
v_emp emp%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
OPEN v_emp_cur FOR
select * from emp WHERE EMP_ID=2;
Loop
    fetch v_emp_cur into v_emp;
    exit when v_emp_cur%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line('Emp_id = '||v_emp.emp_id ||',emp_name = '|| v_emp.emp_name);
end loop;
close v_emp_cur;
END;
/

Comment: why do you use return statement?

Comment: Lalit, I think i have declared ref cursor and it should return something .Please clear me if i am wornge